# http response in a plane txt format

Tags: api, http, request, response

I was validating an API's data. I'm going through the a HTTP response and I was expecting something in json or XML or traditional format but I'm receiving something like this:

```
    -----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="token"

xoxc-5285178979879-5312355007393-5323417324576-49bd3e1a28c6b1fbb344ecf6cfdbfffe8fd6478287a5a3580e98a49a1bbf6842
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version"

5
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_x_reason"

initial-data
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="include_min_version_bump_check"

1
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="version_ts"

1684664853
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="build_version_ts"

1684664853
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_x_sonic"

true
-----------------------------1548889338407418819342511838025--
```

Do you know how to treat such responses if there's anything to validate? Seems pretty obfuscated...

Comment: anyone with Moderator privileges can help me to move to the correct space if needed. Thanks.

Comment: I found that: The HTTP response appears to be a multipart form-data. It is a way to structure data that is being sent over HTTP. In this case, the response contains multiple parts, each separated by a boundary string.

Comment: Looks like you found the answer yourself! Most languages have a multipart parser.